# Bing Maps .v7 How to iterate map.entities?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, bing-maps

I'm adding many polylines to my map. But after some logic I need to iterate the map.entities collection and get all my polylines.

```
              var polylineN = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline(loc);

              // Add the pushpin
              map.entities.push(polylineN);
```

If I iterate my map.entities I get functions, Objects, and many data.
I think I need to use the map.entities.get function to retrieve the correct entities, but how will I know the index length to iterate it?

```
 map.entities.get(0) //works fine
```

Something like:

```
  _.each(map.entities, function(entity){
            console.log(entity); //it returns all kind of data
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated, any javascript iteration sample or underscore iteration sample is valid.

Comment: What does "all kinds of data" look like? What do you want to get instead?

Comment: Looks like functions, undefined, different Objects. I would like to retrieve just my polyline entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found this way of doing it:

```
                var i = 0, entity;
                while (i < map.entities.getLength()) {
                    entity = map.entities.get(i);
                    i += 1;
                }
```

Comment: you could also just use a tradtional for loop as well. for(let i = 0; i < this.map.entities.getLength(); i++)